# How to specify tablespace when creating postgres database?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, server

My postgres server is running out of space when restoring database, after dumping, How can I create a tablespace and specify a new database to that specific location.

Some examples would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PostgreSQL CREATE TABLESPACE statement](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-tablespace/)

```
create database dbname with tablespace = tablespace_name;
```